# excel cell value format is numbers with commas but is shown as all numbers and no commas in address bar

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I have an excel column cell value that is number formatted with commas in the value as well.  However, within the address bar only the numbers exist, no commas are shown.  The value is listed to the bottom right of cell as number format should be.  I also have string or text values listed the same way but on the left side of cell.  No problems with text values.
I know that formatting the cell as text or custom does not change the outcome.  I have tried excel formatting, data text-to-column, excel copy paste special, and python astype column format with no luck.

Examples:
Shown is excel cell.  [123,123,123,123]

What is shown in the excel address bar or within python column print view. [123123123123]

What I'm looking for & context.  The commas actually separate the numbers which are amounts. The above example would be $123 dollars per each night stayed at a hotel which is four nights.  Usually I can do a find and replace and change commas to pipes which is what the overall report will be when completed.

But I can not find a way to change the cell formatting to reflect the same in the address bar.

I hope this makes some sense.  I appreciate if anyone can help with the hurdle.

Comment: How is your question related to python or pandas? How is your question related to programming?

Comment: That is what I'm using to clean the data.  both have ways to format columns which may lead to an answer to may question....

Comment: The problem is that Excel "knows" that [123,123,123,123] is a number (123 billion...), so that's what it stores in the cell. Can you format the column as Text before entering the data? You have to tell Excel ahead of time not to interpret the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Richard.  Unfortunely, I don't have access to the original report.  That is why I'm trying to figure a way to perform fix after the fact.  But I don understand trying to adjust before data goes into the excel column.

Comment: Please show us a sample of the data (as a table rather than a screen shot). If any patterns are apparent you might be able to parse the entries (for example, if they're all 3 digits). Or can you establish a value range, maybe something like $80-$150 per night? That might allow you to tease out values based on the first digit. And was "But I don understand" supposed to be "don't understand" or "do understand"?

Comment: Hope this helps in seeing the issue.  My earlier comment was typo...I meant I do understand trying to adjust before data goes into excel.  These numbers are all amounts and could have periods for cent calculation.  But the common pattern among all is a comma lays between the nightly rate(or each number).  I simply been able to replace all commas with pipes and move on.  But this is becoming a bit of a problem where the data is coming in as a number with commas but doesn't  appear in the address bar.

Comment: If you format the cells in Excel as `text` and then use dtype='object' in pd.read_excel then the string format is preserved - for example `['123,123,123', '1231,23']` as taken from a DataFrame.